# How can I add unique keys to React/Material UI Autocomplete component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm trying to create a Material UI `Autocomplete` component that essentially just displays search results to the user. Some of the options' names will be duplicates, but they will all have unique IDs. I receive the following warning:

> index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Name B`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

```
const SearchField = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('')
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([])
    const loading = true //later

    const debounced = useDebouncedCallback(
        async searchQuery => {
            if (searchQuery) {
                let result = await doSearch(searchQuery)
                if (result.status === 200) {
                    setSearchResults(result.data)
                } else {
                    console.error(result)
                }
            }
        },
        1000
    )

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        if (e.target.value && e.target.value !== searchQuery) {
            debounced(e.target.value)
            setSearchQuery(e.target.value)
        }
    }

    const options = [{
        name: 'Name A',
        id: 'entry_0597856'
    },{
        name: 'Name B',
        id: 'entry_3049854'
    },{
        name: 'Name B',
        id: 'entry_3794654'
    },{
        name: 'Name C',
        id: 'entry_9087345'
    }]


    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id='search_freesolo'
            freeSolo
            selectOnFocus
            clearOnBlur
            handleHomeEndKeys
            autoHighlight
            onInputChange={handleInputChange}
            open={true}
            onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
            loading={loading}
            key={option => option.id}

            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.name}

            renderOption={(props, option) => (
                <Box
                    component='li'
                    {...props}
                >
                    {option.name}
                </Box>
            )}

            renderInput={params => {
                return (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        required
                        id="search_bar"
                        label="Search"
                        InputProps={{
                            ...params.InputProps,
                            endAdornment: (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {loading ? <CircularProgress size={18} /> : null}
                                    {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            )
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            }
            
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can define your own `renderOption` that can return the list item with a correct key value. Your code complains about the duplicated keys because by default, `Autocomplete` [uses the](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3e679ac9e368aeb170d564d206d59913ceca7062/packages/mui-core/src/AutocompleteUnstyled/useAutocomplete.js#L1053-L1054) `getOptionLabel(option)` to retrieve the key:

```
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    return (
      <li {...props} key={option.id}>
        {option.name}
      </li>
    );
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

If it still doesn't work, check your props order, you need to declare the key prop last, if you put it before the props provided by the callback:

```
<Box component='li' key={key} {...props}
```

Then it will be overridden by the `props.key` from MUI. It should be like this:

```
<Box component='li' {...props} key={key}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This works, thank you, however I am hoping to add a few other things later that might not work well inside a <li> (e.g an icon, a date in brackets, things like that). I presume that I can just add a div or a span with the key={option.id} on that, but so I can better understand - what was wrong with my original code? Why does it work fine with <li> but not with <Box component='li'>, even when I add the key={option.id} to the <Box>? Thank you

Comment: @kougami it works fine with `Box`, I've updated the live demo for you. I use `li` for demonstration purpose only (simpler code, easier to understand).

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't working like that for me - when I use <Box component='li' key={option.id}>, option.name seems to be being used for the key. I can see it's working like that in the demo, however the code in the demo is simply from the MUI documentation , rather than my own code, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @kougami you need to declare the `key` prop last, if you put it before the `props` provided by the callback like `<Box component='li' key={} {...props}` then it will be overrided by the `props.key` from MUI.

Comment: That's mad, that it was something so simple. But now I've learnt something, I'll put {...props} first in future! Thanks very much for your help and for helping me to understand.

Comment: This helped me a ton, I didn't realize that the key prop needed to go after the spread. Might be good to note in the answer.

Comment: What is the procedure for Material UI v4? There isn't a `props` parameter into `renderOption`, only `option` and `state`.

Comment: this is assuming you've got an ID in your data model.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution for a few days, and adding the `{...props}` was the magic sauce!  Thanks!
As per the api docs the parameter order is as follows:
`renderOption={(props, option, state, ownerState) => ( ... )}`

Comment: For reference to help others, when I omitted the `{...props}` on the root element of the renderOption's component, it was giving the error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." And if you were to manually add `key={option.id}` and omit the `props` parameter then it would display only the element IDs instead of the label text such as something like `#/properties/field-a/properties/field-a-option-1` and etc for each label, and with no other error messages .